# How to reconfig database using controller in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

is there a way to reconfig database using a `controller` in `codeigniter`?

let say i have this code in database config

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db';
```

Then i want to change to this

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'admin';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_admin';
```

Using `controller` in `codeigniter`. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong in doing that change to `database.php` in `config` folder. Are you getting any error when you change those values?

Comment: nope, i have not getting any error of changing this values in config folder.  But i have some condition to change my default database, to desired database by using the controller. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple database in `database.php` in `config` folder like

```
//database 1 details
$db['db1']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['db1']['username'] = 'root';
$db['db1']['password'] = '';
$db['db1']['database'] = 'db';

//database 2 details
$db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['db2']['username'] = 'admin';
$db['db2']['password'] = 'password';
$db['db2']['database'] = 'db_admin';
```

And you can connect to required database as following in your scripts

```
if(condition){
    $DB = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE);
}
else{
    $DB = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);
}
```

When you connect database like this, you have to use your object name `$DB` rather than `$this`

```
$DB->query();
$DB->result();
```

instead of

```
$this->db->query();
$this->db->result();
```

For more [details](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)

Comment: Sorry, @Lepanto but i have read this answer before in stackoverflow and this is not what i need. What i need is to change the value in default database from the `controller`. Not change/switch to another db i have declared in `database.php`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Inside your controller function specify the conditions and then add the following code:

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "admin";
$config['password'] = "password";
$config['database'] = "db_admin";

$this->load->database($config);
```

Now you can access the new database config. Also disable caching as,

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
```

in your database.php file inside config folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, @AkshayKumar  thanks for your answer, but it didnt work. I have place the code you provide me to the controller, and set my db cache to false. But it didnt work. I check it with `$this->db->list_tables();` but it only show the database table i defined in `database.php` not the database table i define it in `controller` :(. Hope you help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have found the solution. Dont know is better or not. But its better than nothing.

I have tried over

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "admin";
$config['password'] = "password";
$config['database'] = "db_admin";

$this->load->database($config);
```

and tried many ways.. but its always call the `database` from `config` folder

Then i found this basic php method for calling the `database` i desire

like this

```
$dbname = 'my_db';
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", $dbname);

$result = $mysqli->query("query")`  
$result->close();
```

I know how foolish i am, and how silly the answers.. but its better than nothing hahaha

Comment: If you use core PHP in MVC then why are you using Codeigniter..??

Comment: dont know.. what it is better than no working project, or the personal perception thought